# Getting data and display half using script

Tags: linux

I have a list of users with passwords in a file in the following format

```
admin = passwd
user1 = passwd1
user2 = passwd2
```

and so on

I need to get the username to display in a terminal screen through a script but not the password. I can get the password for a specified user as shown below (admin account used):

```
admin=$(awk -F"[ \t]*=[ \t]*" '$1 == "admin" { print $2 }' <file loc>)
```

How would i get the list of users and then display them in csv format in the terminal? would I use something similar to the command above?

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F"[ \t]*=[ \t]*" ' { print $1 }' <file loc>
```

Comment: ok thanks, im still learning these commands, if I wanted to ignore the first line and start from the second, how would it be incorporated into that command?

Comment: It isnt it puts each one on a new line, whow would i also replace the new line character with ", "

Comment: csv implies fixed length records. What you want is not a csv file.  Try `awk -v  ORS=,  -F"[ \t]*=[ \t]*" ' { print $1 }' <file loc>`

Comment: Got it working as I want it, I used this: awk -F"[ \t]*=[ \t]*" ' { printf "%s, ", $1 }' <file loc>